# OAuth Login using Blizzard / Battlenet

Tags: reactjs, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, battlenet-api

I’m trying to create a react app and I have no idea how this Blizzard Oauth works?
I’ve spent almost 5 hours reading the documentation, haven't figured out anything.
the only thing I’ve got so far is the “code”.

```
<OauthSender
authorizeUrl=“https://us.battle.net/oauth/authorize”
clientId=“Using My Client ID here”
redirectUri=“http://localhost:3000/games/”
state={{ from: ‘/settings’ }}
render={({ url }) => Login Using Blizzard}
/>
```

Here is the [link](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/battle-net/oauth-apis) to the documentation.

it’s taking me to the blizzard login page and once I log in, it’s redirecting me back to `http://localhost:3000/games/` with code next to it, how do I move further?